# mdframed and skipbelow

Tags: mdframed

There are many questions online concerning this issue of `skipbelow` of the `mdframed` package. For me, this [skipbelow issue](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/issues/12) is not resolved. The version of the `mdframed` package on my system is:

> mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed

If I understand well this is the last one. Is there an issue with the update?

Comment: Can you please say what the "issue" is and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)?

Comment: @Andrew the issue is illustrated at the provided link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fix was indeed applied, but the new version has never been pulled.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\endmdframed}
  {\aftergroup\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup}
  {\endmdf@trivlist\color@endgroup\@doendpe}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text before.

\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=3cm, skipbelow=3cm]
  Testing 123.
\end{mdframed}

Some text after.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance to see the corrected version available on CTAN?

Comment: @user94293 I think that development of `mdframed` has stopped. Using `tcolorbox` is recommended.